Can I assume ctx is always non-null when overriding methods in ANTLR's BaseListener?
I'm currently working with ANTLR and overriding methods in the generated BaseListener class. Specifically, I want to know if I can safely assume that the ctx (context) parameter passed to these overridden methods is always non-null.
For example, if I override a listener method like this:
@Override
public void enterExpr(MyGrammarParser.ExprContext ctx) {
    // Can I assume 'ctx' is always non-null here?
}

Are there any edge cases (like certain parsing errors or optional rules) where ctx could be null, or is it always guaranteed to be a valid context object when the method is called?

I'd say you can assume it is non-null since that method would only be called if there is some expression that has been identified (so no parse error and if optional it is present). However, if you're unsure why not just add a null check at the beginning?

Calling a listener method without providing it the current context is kind of pointless and would indicate an error within ANTLR. For most of our code being prepared for errors in the libraries that we use is IMHO not necessary (as opposed for example to being prepared for infrastructure problems like broken database connections).

Yes, parameter ctx is not null. The CSharp target-generated code, which is a straightforward port from Java, has [NotNull] attributes for the parameter.

Yes you can. The context is allways created, and if you check the generated code, you can see the context as uses 'this' when the correspoding listener function is called, so it must be exist!
